# Não consigo concluir o comando push, o comando inicia a execução mas não conclui

Tags: git, github

Após realizar os passos abaixo o push foi iniciado porém não foi concluído, apenas não conclui, não exibe nenhuma mensagem.

```
$ git init
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "commit inicial"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/anthony-farias/projeto-dotnet.git
$ git push origin master
```

[image: Não sai desse ponto]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entrei no seu git pelo link não seria master e sim main;

```
$ git init
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "commit inicial"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/anthony-farias/projeto-dotnet.git
$ git push origin main
```

Comment: Realmente esse era o erro, obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score -3):

Fala ai, Eu tenho um vídeo no youtube que talvez te ajude a resolver esse problema.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgoZoA3b9VI&t=111s